# Python library for simulation and bifurcation studies of dynamical systems

Tags: library, python, math, scientific-computing

What are libraries available in Python for the simulation and bifurcation study of dynamical systems?

I want to simulate a model based on four or five ODEs, and build bifurcation maps, based on two parameters.
For this I need time series of 40000 data points to classify the morphology for each point in parameter space.
Speed matters even though I have access to a cluster with Python.

I know PyDSTool; is there another alternative?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I authored a Python module named [JiTCODE](https://github.com/neurophysik/jitcode), which is intended for the dynamical-systems community.
Here are some features or missing features that my be relevant for you:

- The right-hand site of the differential equation is just-in-time-compiled, which makes integration rather fast.
  For smaller systems such as yours, there may still be a relevant overhead though (as compared to a pure C program, for example).
  Its performance is comparable or better than that of PyDSTool (see Fig. 5 in [the accompanying paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.1063/1.5019320)).
- It allows you to change control parameters at run-time, thus avoiding frequent re-compilation when scanning a parameter space.
- It neither offers dedicated tools for detecting and determining the type of bifurcations nor continuisation.
  However, since the input is symbolic, it is not a big step to use symbolic equation solvers to find fixed points and determine their stability.
- It does allow you to almost automatically determine regular and transversal Lyapunov exponents.

Answer (score 2):

You could install [Netlogo](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/). It is a free java-based GUI tool, but it has some language bindings for "remote-controlling" it and fetching the results. It has a large models-library with lots of useful and preconfigured models, [some of which](http://www.intro-to-abm.com/#models2) might suit your needs.

In [this post on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49807171/202553) someone mentions a new Python API, [PyNetLogo](http://pynetlogo.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), but I haven't used that API yet and  cannot tell how good it is.

Comment: Thanks, I will have a look with more attention, but I was maybe looking for something more specific to ODE